# Failed to install native resource : Linux-lib.jar - SAP client installatiion

Tags: java, ubuntu, sap-gui

I am trying to install SAP client for linux (Ubuntu 18.04).

I downloaded and updated the right prerequisites, and then ran the command:

`java -jar PlatinGUI740_7-20012037.JAR`
(tried also with version PlatinGUI750_0-80002494.JAR)

The installation window opens, and when trying to install, I get an error:
[image: Error message]

The error: `Failed to install native resource : Linux-lib.jar`

Will be happy for your ideas to solve this problem,

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you install under root or under regular user? It is recommended to do it under your user

Comment: I first tried to install under my user, and later on also tried under root.. both didn't work unfortunately

Comment: And what is written in `/home/nadav/sapgui.log`? Also make sure your archive with SAPgui is not corrupted.

Comment: I checked the .log file.. It contains the error which appears on the picture I added.

Comment: What is your Java version? Is it Oracle or OpenJDK? Make sure you have JDK not JRE.

Comment: I tried both of them.. can you recommend (maybe add a link) to any version that should work?

Comment: It's not a question of "recommend me", it's a question of "yes or no". [SAP guidelines](http://jsfiddle.net/tbfawrLn/1/show#Linux) strictly define this point and non-Oracle version will simple **not** work. You need Oracle Java SE 8 32- or 64-bit (update 40 or newer)

Comment: And don't forget to completely wipe out old versions of java nefore that. For example [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)